# Black " administrator" screen when connecting

Tags: rdp

would anyone know how I can get passed this screen, im fairly new to this and have had other instances connected using RDP work just fine.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Write explorer and press enter. It will work, except if it's a core install, like the answer already said.

Answer (score 3):

That's a [Windows Core server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/what-is-server-core).

> When you finish installing Server Core on a system and sign in for the first time, you're in for a bit of a surprise. The main difference between the Server with Desktop Experience installation option and Server Core is that Server Core does not include the following GUI shell packages:
>
> - Microsoft-Windows-Server-Shell-Package
> - Microsoft-Windows-Server-Gui-Mgmt-Package
> - Microsoft-Windows-Server-Gui-RSAT-Package
> - Microsoft-Windows-Cortana-PAL-Desktop-Package
>
> In other words, there is **no desktop** in Server Core, by design.

It doesn't have a desktop, only a command prompt. Usually you manage it remotely with the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT).

Comment: Thanks for the response just switched servers. Didn't know that's what server core did :)

Comment: If this answered your question please accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left, so the question can be marked as "solved" in the system.